# how can I hide a popup box when the user clicks elsewhere?

Tags: jquery

My popup box appears when I click on the button, and it only disappears when I click again on the button. This is my code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('a.signUp, a.signIn').click(function() {

        //Getting the variable's value from a link 
        var popupBox = $(this).attr('href');

        if ($(popupBox).css('display')=='none'){
            // Add the mask to body
            $('#mask').show();
            //Fade in the Popup
            $(popupBox).fadeIn(300);
        } else {
            //Fade out box, and hide the mask
            $(popupBox).fadeOut(300 , function() {
                $('#mask').hide();  
            }); 
        }
        return false;

        });

    });
```

So there are two button, made with  and that is why I get the variables value from a link. How can I make the boxes disappear when I click anywhere outside the box?

Comment: Bind to a `$(document).click()` and make sure the `e.target!=popupBox`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
   $(popupBox).on("click", function(e){
      e.stopPropagation();
    });


    $(document).on("click", function() {
      $(popupBox).hide("fast");
    });
```

Comment: Just curious; But do you know if using the `document` for an event would be a bigger request to handle than say using the mask or another element?

Comment: Well,Some requirements push us to use them.

Comment: I am trying this, but maybe not the correct way... I haven't used this, I I don't know how to do it...sorry for being such a noob :(

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
    var container = $('.popup');
    if (container.is(':visible') && container.has(e.target).length === 0)
        container.fadeOut('fast');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.blur()](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) event or [focusout()](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/) method for this. It would do the trick for you.

```
$('#popBoxWrapperDiv').blur(function(){
//hide the popup box
});
```